# How to sort PivotTable by a specific column?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a PivotTable that is structured as follows:

```
ROWS> article numbers
COLS> week dates
VALUES > sales amount
```

I want to sort the article numbers by the largest sales in the last(latest) week number. But I have no idea how to do this. The default sort options only allow sorting the Grand Total, which doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you said, by default Excel sorts by *Grand Total*, but you can change this. First go to the *More Sort Options...* menu:

[image: Pivot Table menu]

Then select in the sort options to sort ascending or descending by the *sales amount* (in my example *sum of sales*). Then click on *More Options...*:

[image: More Sort Options]

Now you can should select *Values in selected column*. You'll see that it refers to the first row of the *Grand Total* column (in my example this was `$E$5`), now change this to your last week's column (in my example `$D$5`).

Comment: Hi, I tried this on a simple pivot and it worked great! However, when I added additional value fields to the columns, so that each week had 3 data points - it didn't work. I get the error "auto sort and auto show cannot be used with custom calculations". Is that a limitation or am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: When I add a value column (for example *count of article*) it adds a column for each week, but the sorting keeps working. And if I check in the sorting, it updated it to the new column location which contained the *sum of sales* for week 3 (`$F$6` in my example).

Comment: I think I have discovered my issue. I am using the option for one of my value fields to show "difference from" of Week # versus previous week (in 'show values as' options). Doing this will break the sort option - which is a shame!!